# Using Migrate API to select items from a JSON array

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a module pulling a JSON feed into Drupal 8 using the Migrate API. However, one of the values in the JSON is an array.

For example, `coordinates`:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "id:1",
            "position": {
                "coordinates": [
                    24.932974,
                    60.168495
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "id:2",
            "position": {
                "coordinates": [
                    24.94416,
                    60.18831
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            ...
        },
...
```

What sort of field selector is needed to get `coordinates`?

If I use `selector: position/coordinates` I get 24.932974.

- How would I get the second one: 60.168495?
- Should the [`extract`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process/process-plugin-extract) plugin be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a selector like this:

```
-
  name: position
  label: 'Position'
  selector: position
```

Then use this for the first value:

```
field_description:
  plugin: extract
  source: position
  index:
    - coordinates
    - 0
```

And this for the second value:

```
field_description:
  plugin: extract
  source: position
  index:
    - coordinates
    - 1
```